# In postgis, what is the difference between Z-Dimension and M-Dimension

Tags: geometry, postgis

Just as the title, **what is the difference between `Z-Dimension` and `M-Dimension` in `postgis`?**

It is said that Z-Dimension generally stores elevation information while M-Dimension stores some other information.

However, is there any substantial difference between Z-Dimension and M-Dimension? For example, **is there any difference in spect of the functions offered by postgis?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference in that PostGIS treats the Z coordinate different in three-dimensional functions.

Consider this example:

```
SELECT st_3ddistance(
          'SRID=4326;POINT ZM(0 0 0 100)'::geometry,
          'SRID=4326;POINT ZM(0 0 0 0)'::geometry
       );

 st_3ddistance 
═══════════════
             0
(1 row)

SELECT st_3ddistance(
          'SRID=4326;POINT ZM(0 0 100 0)'::geometry,
          'SRID=4326;POINT ZM(0 0 0 0)'::geometry
       );

 st_3ddistance 
═══════════════
           100
(1 row)
```

The M dimension can be any measure associated with each point, for example the intensity of the radioactive radiation in that location. Obviously, that does not factor in distance measurements. It is used in other functions like [`ST_InterpolatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_InterpolatePoint.html), which interpolates the M dimension at a given point:

```
SELECT st_interpolatepoint(
          'SRID=4326;LINESTRING ZM(0 0 0 100,50 50 10 0)'::geometry,
          'SRID=4326;POINT(20 20)'::geometry
       );

 st_interpolatepoint 
═════════════════════
                  60
(1 row)
```

Here the Z coordinate is ignored, since it is a function for 2-dimensional geometry.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's helpful to a certain extent. Could you please show me more related information about this or just show me some more systematic web pages to introduce this problem?

Comment: I cannot provide that. I'd say that it is pretty obvious what a Z dimension is: altitude.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thanks again, that's good enough!

Comment: Just one more question, can I use 3-D spatial index on M-dimension if I create a geometry of type `LinestringM`? For example, I set the `time` attribute as M-dimension, whether I can use 3-D spatial index in time dimension or not?

Comment: This description could be another question —— What's the advantage of setting the `time` attribute as M-dimension of a geometry comparing to setting the `time` attribute as a ordinary RDB attribute along with a 2D geometry?

In other words, whether it makes retrieving geometryies in a certain period more easy by using M-dimension `time` attribute than using a separate index of `time` attribute?

Comment: I have added a function that uses the M coordinate. But it is impossible to be exhaustive.

Comment: I have added more information about my question, may be it's helpful to solve it.

Comment: I tried to answer the question indicated by the question title and the original question. Now you added something about index usage, which sounds quite unrelated to the original question. Sure, everything has to do with geometries. I think you should ask a second question about index usage in PostGIS, otherwise the question loses the required focus.